# Excel creation with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I was using Apache POI 3.7 to create Excel with `HSSF`. It was working fine. But during load test, I realized that it is very slow. So I Googled and found I can use `SXSSF`. I changed my existing code to `XSSF`. The result was awesome.

But I stuck with a situation, `autorezisecolum()` is not functioning as expected. It displays large contents as `#####`, because the column width shrinks. I found it is a kind of a bug already raised.

Now my point is, is there any solution so that i can use `SXSSF`(very important for performance) with a nice output.

Note: I am using Windows 7, JDK 1.7.09 , POI-3.10.beta-2

Please help me.

Here is my code :

Main Function :

```
sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(5);        
sxssfSheet = (SXSSFSheet) sxssfWorkbook.createSheet(sheetName); 
try {
    // TO Write Header
    //ew.writeHeaderRow(sheet, headerNames);
    ew.writeHeaderRow(sxssfSheet, headerNames);
    int rowNum = headerRow + 1;
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> columnData : columnDataMap.entrySet()){
        ew.writeNonHeaderRow(sxssfSheet, columnData.getValue(), rowNum);
        rowNum++;
    }
resizeXLSXColumns(sxssfSheet,rowNum-1);
sxssfWorkbook.write(outputStream);
outputStream.close();



public void writeHeaderRow(Sheet sheet, List<String> headerNames ) {
//public void writeHeaderRow(SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet, List<String> headerNames ) {
    // LinkedHashMap<String,Object> mp = getFieldNames(obj);
  //  ArrayList<String> colNames = (ArrayList<String>) getColumnNames();

    try {
        XSSFCellStyle hCellStyle = getHeaderStyle();
        SXSSFRow row = (SXSSFRow) sheet.createRow(headerRow);
        for (int hCellInd = 0; hCellInd < headerNames.size(); hCellInd++) {
            SXSSFCell cell = (SXSSFCell) row.createCell(hCellInd);
            cell.setCellStyle(hCellStyle);
            cell.setCellValue(headerNames.get(hCellInd));
            //sheet.autoSizeColumn(hCellInd);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeNonHeaderRow(SXSSFSheet sxssfSheet, List<Object> rowObj, int rowIndex)                     
{    
CreationHelper createHelper = sxssfWorkbook.getCreationHelper();        
try {
        SXSSFRow row = (SXSSFRow)sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
        XSSFCellStyle normalStyle = getNormalStyle();
        int count = 0;
        for (int rCellInd = 0; rCellInd < rowObj.size(); rCellInd++) {
            //Cell cell = row.createCell(rCellInd);
            SXSSFCell cell = (SXSSFCell)row.createCell(rCellInd);
            cell.setCellStyle(normalStyle);
            Object cellData = rowObj.get(rCellInd);
            if (cellData != null) {
                if (cellData instanceof Double) {                                   
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) cellData);
                    if((Double)cellData < 0){
                        cell.setCellStyle(getNegativeValueStyle());
                    }else if((Double)cellData == 0){
                        normalStyle.setDataFormat((short) SXSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) ;
                        cell.setCellStyle(normalStyle);
                    }else
                        cell.setCellStyle(normalStyle);                    
            } else {
                //normalStyle.setDataFormat((short) HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                cell.setCellType(SXSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
            }
            //sxssfSheet.autoSizeColumn();
            //sxssfSheet.setColumnWidth(rCellInd, sxssfSheet.getColumnWidth(rCellInd));
            //resizeXLSXColumns(sheet);
        }
        //autoResizeColumns(sxssfSheet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void resizeXLSXColumns(Sheet sheet ,int rowNum){

    SXSSFRow row = (SXSSFRow)sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    Iterator<Cell> itr = row.cellIterator();
    int max = 0;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Cell cell = itr.next();
        int width = sheet.getColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex());
        if(width > max){
            max = width;
        }
        //sheet.setColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex(),max);
    }
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Cell cell = itr.next();
        sheet.setColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex(),max);
    }
}
```

Comment: apache poi 3.7 should work fine. optimize your code.

Comment: Shubham: You should call autoresizecolumn() at the end, just before performing the write() method.

Comment: @Ved : XSSF is having facility to pass the number of rows to write, in constructor.(Kind of batch ) . That's how it wrote very fast.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh : I have tried like u said . Didn't work :(

Comment: Share your code with us...

Comment: @Sankumarsingh : shared

Comment: share resizeXLSXColumns(sxssfSheet,rowNum-1); method

Comment: @Sankumarsingh : I have shared this method as well. Since i have tried in many ways , so may be u wonder by seeing code . Anyway if u get any idea ,please share.

Comment: Just one thought , i am expecting the autosize is only taking first row (in my case header row. If i remove data , then i can see the header size properly)